# Generate two objects from one xml document with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm creating a rest api that will consume an xml document and create two objects from that document. The objects will then be persisted on a database using hibernate. This is what I have right now:

```
@PUT
@Path("saveVehicle")
@Consumes("application/xml;charset=utf-8")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String saveVehicleData(String xml) {
    DBClient client = new DBClient();
    Session session = client.getVehicleSession();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    try {
        Reader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xmlReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);

        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(VehicleData.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        VehicleData vehicle = (VehicleData) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader);

        session.saveOrUpdate(vehicle);
        session.flush();

        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(VehicleOwner.class);
        jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        VehicleOwner owner = (VehicleOwner) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader);

        session.saveOrUpdate(owner);
        session.flush();

        return vehicle.getRegistrationNo() + " " + owner.getName();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "JAXBException " + e.getMessage() + "\nCaused by " + e.getCause();
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "XMLStreamException " + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this method is supposed to take in xml as a string. It will then generate a vehicle and a vehicle owner from that document. The document contains information about vehicles and their owners but I want them in separate database tables.
The classes use jaxb annotations for all the fields that I want to store on the database. 
However, When I try to run this, I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.package.VehicleOwner cannot be cast to org.package.VehicleData
org.package.rest.LoginController.saveVehicleData(LoginController.java:369)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Before I added the mapping for vehicle owners, I was able to instantiate a `VehicleData` and store it on the database. But now it seems like it is expecting this xml document to be mapped to a `VehicleOwner`. I thought it would be possible to map the document to different classes. Is that not the case? if it is, How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to map document to different classes, but apparently you don't do this. Just doing:

```
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(VehicleData.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    VehicleData vehicle = (VehicleData) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader);
```

Does not magically map you XML structure to `VehicleData` structure. You have to define or generate mappings so that the same XML would map to different structures (`VehicleData`/`VehicleOwner`) in different JAXB contexts. You also have to make sure these contexts do not intersect (I guess they do in your case).

Comment: I noticed that I was using the same context for both classes so I fixed that and updated the code in the question. However I still get the same error. I dont think I really understand your answer. This is the frst time I try to use jaxb so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. Could you explain further what you mean when you say "You have to define or generate mappings so that the same XML would map to different structures" and what it means when contexts intersects?